# how can I retrieve specific property of an object of multiple objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need help in getting values of specific property of an array of multiple objects
I have an array like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "skill 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "skill 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "skill 3"
    }]
```

and I want to get a string like this :

```
skill 1 - skill 2 - skill 3
```

Comment: Please read through [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. *(not my downvote)*

Comment: Too trivial for a full answer `myArray.map((v) => v.name).join(" - ")` would do the trick.

Comment: @DBS - Clunky, hard to read, easy to get wrong, and hard to debug. Outside functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions, `reduce` is just an overcomplicated loop. Use a loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to extract name. You can use `map`.

```js
elements.map(x=>x.name)
```

Second step is to join it to one string using `join`

```js
const result = elements.map(x=>x.name).join(' - ');
```